# Как узнать id человека который зашел на сайт?(Без php)

Tags: javascript

Хочется средствами js узнать id пользователя и в зависимости от него показать данные(Сайт для друзей) Знаю что информацию от вк можно получить только путем авторизации, интересует возможно ли сделать это без php. Документация ВК для меня является слишком непонятной тк я только начал

Comment: А при чем тут php если речь идет о js? Можете свой вопрос сделать более развернутым?

Comment: Как я понял авторизацию без php сделать невозможно, но мне не нужна полная авторизация

Comment: Можно сделать? Можно. Использовать OpenAPI. Он использует только js. PHP - не требуется